# interpretation of debugging information in assemble language

Tags: debugging, assembly

```
   0x00473a28 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x00473a29 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00473a2b <+3>: sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x00473a2e <+6>: call   0x419150 <mcount>
   0x00473a33 <+11>:    mov    %ecx,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x00473a36 <+14>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
=> 0x00473a39 <+17>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x00473a3b <+19>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x00473a3e <+22>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x00473a40 <+24>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00473a43 <+27>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x00473a46 <+30>:    call   0x4837c8 <std::forward<hash_tree_node*&>(std::remove_reference<hash_tree_node*&>::type&)>
   0x00473a4b <+35>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x00473a4d <+37>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x00473a50 <+40>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%eax)
   0x00473a53 <+43>:    leave  
   0x00473a54 <+44>:    ret    $0x8
```

I'm not so familiar about assemble language,what sort of problem does the pointed line indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with the line prior to the one you are pointing to.

```
   0x00473a36 <+14>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
```

This instruction is taking the first argument passed to your function (the function you are currently examining) and storing that value into `%eax`.

```
=> 0x00473a39 <+17>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
```

This instruction is now assuming that the value in `%eax` is a valid address that exists within your application's allowable address space. It fetches the 32-bit value at that address and puts that value into `%edx`.

The problem that can occur is if you pass, as the first argument to this function, and invalid address (an address that is not within your application's allowable address space). You can get a segmentation fault, for example, if this happens, or possibly just undefined behavior.

If you want to examine it further, you can look at the value of `%eax` at this point and see if it looks like a reasonable address. Or go to the source code where this function is called and examine what is being passed as the first argument to the function and determine if it's a valid pointer to your application's data or data from the heap that has been properly allocated.